# C# - application runs much more slowly after being published from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've written a windows form application using C# in Visual Studio 2008. It involves a lot of calculations. When I build it and run it in VS 2008, it takes some time and it's able to produce results I wanted. However, when I published it from VS into a *.application file, it runs much more slowly.

May I know how to solve this problem? I need to demo the software thus I need the stand-along application to run equally fast.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please define 'slowly'. According to your text, you published the application with ClickOnce? What if you just run the executable?

Comment: I think you should publish your application in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a profiler to see what is taking the time...

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?gclid=CJ_a4ZnxuagCFQoY4QodFGfACQ

It is also sensible to suggest that you make sure you compile your application in release mode as it will remove all of the debug overhead in the running application.